# Mysql search in database

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have name,surname,city,address,mobile fields in mysql table.
I want a select statement that select all the records if any of the above fields data matches;

For eg: If i put name: yusuf. then select statement should look data :yusuf in all column mentioned above and if any of the record matches then it should show the result.

Comment: You need to use a LIKE comparison http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Have you tried looking into `WHERE` ?

Comment: I have used like. but it work only at one column but i want to search in multiple column.

Comment: You need to use multiple `LIKES` and `OR`

Comment: Add query which you tried

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you search by name.

Then use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE userinput`.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,surname,city,address,mobile  from Table
where name like '%Yusuf%'
Or Surname like '%Yusuf%'
or City like '%Yusuf%'
Or Address like '%Yusuf%'
Or Mobile like '%Yusuf%'
```